# resize containers to not exceed their main parent when main parent is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a website in which there are mulitple post in form of blocks with each block of different height . I wanted to make a system in when i resize the window of the browser and then the main container's height also becomes less and the its children in which the child is going to exceed the height of the main container also resize . I was able to make the system using jquery but when i maximize the window the child element which was resized is now of less size then original one .

```
jQuery('.mi-module-cnt').each(function(index, element) {

var jsp_height=jQuery(".jspContainer,.jspPane").height();

var module_height=jQuery(this).height();

    if (module_height>jsp_height)   
    {
        jQuery(this).height(jsp_height);

    }
    else
    {
        jQuery(this).height(module_height);
    }

});
```

Can i make the child elements return to their original height when maximizing height too ? it currently works on minimize when the height also gets minimized according the parent container'e height

Comment: Would using @media queries and set 'height' to a % of the parents do what you're asking or am I misreading your question?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is to, in the "else" part, set the height to "auto".

```
else {
  jQuery(this).height("auto");
}
```

That should take it back to whatever height it was is naturally before any explicit resizing.

Here is a fiddle with an example of this: http://jsfiddle.net/7t04byqn/. Stretch the bar of the "Result" window up and down to see the effect taking place. (Though for some reason, it seems to be rather temperamental, and the resizing of excessive items (when the "if" is true) doesn't always seem to work on every window resize, especially on Firefox.  But hopefully it will give you the basic idea.)